# Permissions for SSL key?

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, nginx, openssl

I'm trying to set up a secure connection (https) in nginx.

But I'm a bit worried about the private key's permissions, which aren't mentioned in any tutorial.

Should I change them? To what?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Private keys should have reading heavily restricted. Setting permissions to `600` and owned by `root` should work. However, there are other secure permissions settings - Ubuntu stores keys in a directory with owner `root` and group `ssl-cert` and permissions `710`. This means that only members of `ssl-cert` can access any files in that directory. Private keys then have group `ssl-cert`, owner `root`, and permissions `640`.

Comment: I'll add, for specificity: When using nginx on CentOS 7, it is not necessary to make either the certificate or the private key readable by those in the `nginx` group. The webserver will be able to use them even if they are readable only by `root` (as they should be).

Comment: Just to recap: the private key(s) can be owned by root with `600` ([or even `000` for that matter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303811/can-super-user-write-into-read-only-files)) when NGINX is started as `root`, because the master process will act as `root` and only the worker processes are started as the specified system user (e.g., with the [`user`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user) directive). Right? (**edit**: I got my answer in the [next answer](https://superuser.com/a/1250447/372910).)

Answer (score 7):

I had an issue getting nginx setup and came across this question. The other answer here has already directly answered the question but I thought a little more information would be helpful.

Normally, nginx is started as the `root` user by init scripts / systemd. However, nginx also has the ability to switch to a less privileged user for normal operations. So my question was which user is used to load the ssl certificate/key? The initial privileged user or the one that is switched to?

Fortunately, nginx uses the initial permissions to read the certificate and key into memory before switching users. So, normally, you really can leave the keys with very restricted permissions as they are loaded by nginx when it's still running as `root`.

---

The problem that I was running into that landed me here was that I was defining `ssl_certificate` only in my `server` blocks in `nginx.conf`. I was getting errors like `[error] 18606#18606: *311 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking` when I knew darn good and well that my keys were in the right place. That issue was that I didn't have a `ssl_certificate` at the `http` level of `nginx.conf`.

Hope this is helpful for someone.